# is there a way to not dismiss the keyboard when closing parent component in react native

Tags: ios, react-native, keyboard, expo

I am currently opening the keyboard automatically as soon as the parent component or the modal is visible, which is what I want but the problem is that when I dismiss the modal first the keyboard will be dismissed, and then the modal will be dismissed which is causing bad UI interactivity. I would like to keep the keyboard still and only dismiss the parent component or the modal instead of both. I am using scrollView inside KeyboardAvoidingView while keyboardShouldPersistTapsis set to "always". you can find my code below:

```
    const amountInput = () => (
    <View style={styles.inputAndTextContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>ETB</Text>
      <TextInput
        onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
          return nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace' ? clearLastChar() : null;
        }}
        caretHidden
        ref={textInputRef}
        style={styles.inputStyle}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        defaultValue={amount.value}
        /* value={amount.value} */
        autoFocus
        maxLength={6}
        onChangeText={num => {
          setAmount({ value: addCommaToNumber(num) });
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );

   return (
    <View>
      <Modal
        isVisible={isVisible}
        animationIn="bounceInUp"
        animationOut="slideOutDown"
        animationOutTiming={200}
        animationInTiming={200}
        style={{ margin: 0 }}
      >
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
          <Header />
          <ScrollView
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
            alwaysBounceVertical={false}
          >
            {amountInput()}
            {state && state.length ? someFunc() : anotherFunc()}
          </ScrollView>

          {renderModal()}
          {state ? someFunc() : someotherfunc()}
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </Modal>
    </View>
    )
```